# count rows after lines matched with pattern

Tags: text-processing, command-line

How can I count the rows between patterns and redirect the rows count on file?

example:

```
PATTERN FOUND 
rows 
rows 
rows 
PATTERN FOUND 
rows 
rows
```

Expected result should be:

```
3
2
```

Comment: Is the answer 3 or 3,2?

Comment: the answer that i expect is: 3,2,x,n,y etc..etc..

Comment: what does "redirect the raw counts on file" mean?

Comment: for example
cat pattern_file | while read lines; do <some command tath return the number of line> > OUT_FILE_COUNT_RAW; done

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk -v RS='PATTERN FOUND' 'NF{print NF}' infile
3
2
```

Or if your `rows` are actually a set of sentences, you can do:

```
$ awk -v RS='PATTERN FOUND' -F'\n' 'NF{print NF-2}' infile >output
```

Above `awk` on below sample input file:

```
PATTERN FOUND
rows
rows
rows
PATTERN FOUND
rows
rows
Here PATTERN FOUND :
zero first
second

fourth fifth sixth and last
```

Will give you the result:

```
3
2
4
```

---

To get rid of empty lines and don't count them:

```
awk -v RS='PATTERN FOUND' -F'(\n)+' 'NF{print NF-2}' infile
```

and to get rid of empty lines and those contains only whitespace (Tabs or Spaces):

```
awk -v RS='PATTERN FOUND' -F'(\n|^[ \t]*$)+' 'NF{print NF-2}' infile
```